# Use hardwareAcceleration flag with Canvas.clipPath

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, opengl-es-2.0, android-canvas

I'm porting a project made for the Galaxy Tab 1, for Galaxy Tab 2, but the apk runs slowly so I added the hardwareAccelerated flag on the AndroidManifest.XML of the new application.

But running give me the following error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
     at android.view.GLES20Canvas.clipPath(GLES20Canvas.java:287)
     at br.com.iba.view.PageCurlView.drawCurl(PageCurlView.java:284)
     at br.com.iba.view.PageCurlView.onDraw(PageCurlView.java:353)
     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:9291)
```

Comment: [This article](http://android-developers.blogspot.se/2011/03/android-30-hardware-acceleration.html) about hardware acceleration might help you.

Comment: Thanks, it's looks good. But the problem I mentioned here is a CustomView that has all the logics and views inner it, I cannot disable hardwareAcceleration just for that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the similar problem in my project with ImageView which doesn't support hardware acceleration. I circumvented this problem with this code:

`mImageView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);`

It work's for me.

Comment: Well, disabling it works, but run slowly as no hardwareAcceleration is used.

Answer (score 3):

To prevent issues related to the version of the sdk, you should use:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
    mapView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
}
```

I was getting `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: setLayerType`.

This post is only for clarifying things.