# UnsupportedOperationException in custom view

Tags: android, user-interface

I have a custom view which throws on some devices the UnsupportedOperationException. It looks like that:

```
 java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
     at android.view.GLES20Canvas.clipPath(GLES20Canvas.java:287)
     [...]
```

I know there's the setLayerType method but this is only supported since API level 11. How do I  fix that problem for API level 8?

Here's a similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401319/use-hardwareacceleration-flag-with-canvas-clippath) but the solution doesn't work for me because I'm using API level 8.

Answer (score 2):

You can define `layerType` in layout XML.

```
<com.nth.android.ui.view.CircularProgressBar
    android:layout_width="96dp"
    android:layout_height="96dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:src="@android:color/black"
    android:layerType="software" />
```

The project where I've used features unsupported by hardware acceleration had target SDK version set to 14 and minimum SDK version was 8. Attribute `layerType="software"` worked on both Honeycomb (Android 3.2) and Gingerbread (Android 2.3.3).

Also, in some cases `layerType="software"` has to be set for view groups (layouts) that contain view in question.

Comment: The problem there is, if the user is forcing hardware acceleration the app still crashes. You can also force software mode in the android manifest but the user overrules your settings anyway. The only real safe way is to remove this method calls altogether. It's on my list to remove the calls and find a OpenGl replacement. +1 anyway, I didn't know that.